# Increasing windows clipboard history size by reverse engineering

Tags: windows, reverse-engineering, ghidra

I'm trying to increase the clipboard history size of the clipboard manager in windows (That is the clipboard that shows when you press `Win+V`). It shows your copy history but only your last 25 copies which is a shame if you want to keep a larger history size.

I'm aware of other clipboard managers that can be installed on windows, but I'm interested in increasing the history limit on the windows default one because I think it's a good exercise in reverse engineering. From what I searched, windows has no registry entry to change this limit.

My suspition is that this limit would be implemented in the `ShellExperienceHost.exe` but I looked there for a while in ghidra and couldn't find anything related (I found a copyToClipboard string but that's it). Am I looking in the correct place?